# What would be the join and meet of this lattice?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $W$ be a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{K}^n$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field of characteristic $0$. Let $L$ denote the set of supports of all vectors in $W$, ordered by reverse inclusion. Show that $L$ is a geometric lattice.

**I will mention that for any $v=(v_1, \ldots , v_n)$, $\,$ $\text{supp}(v)=\left\{i: v_i\neq 0 \right\}$.

First I need to show that $L$ is semimodular, so I will show that if $\text{supp}(v)$ and $\text{supp}(u)$ both cover $\,$ $\text{supp}(v) \wedge \text{supp}(u)$ $\,$ then $\,$ $\text{supp}(v) \vee \text{supp}(u)$ $\,$ cover both $\,$ $\text{supp}(v)$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\text{supp}(u)$.

Here is my issue: I want to safely say that since $\text{supp}(v) \subseteq [n]$ that $\,$ $\text{supp}(v) \vee \text{supp}(u)= \text{supp}(v) \cup \text{supp}(u)$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\text{supp}(v) \wedge \text{supp}(u)= \text{supp}(v) \cap \text{supp}(u)$. However, how do I know that $L$ is closed under unions and intersections to begin with? Perhaps I'm wrong and the join and meet of any two elements in $L$ is some other set. Help me, please! Thank you!

Comment: @celtschk Sorry, I edited my post. I wrote the definition above.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; with that definition, my comment doesn't apply, therefore I deleted it.

Comment: Union is meet.  This is because supp($x$) $\wedge$ supp($y$) is supposed to be a superset of both supp($x$) and supp($y$) (note that supports are ordered by reverse inclusion), so supp($x$) $\wedge$ supp($y$) is at least as big as supp($x$) $\cup$ supp($y$), and in fact, the union is in $L$, since it is the support of $x + \alpha y$ for a generic $\alpha$.  However, join will not be intersection, since there is no reason for the intersection of two supports to be the support of something in $W$.

Comment: @HughThomas Ahh, you're right, union is meet (I forgot that $L$ is ordered by reverse inclusion). What would the join be then?

Comment: It doesn't have a simple description just in terms of set theory.  A good example to think about is $W$ in $\mathbb R^3$ defined by $x+y+z=0$.  The possible supports are $\emptyset$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$.  On the other hand, you could also take $W$ to be all of $\mathbb R^3$, in which case you get all subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$.  So the join of $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ is different in the two cases.

Comment: @HughThomas Great examples, thank you. Now I know that $\,$ $\text{supp}(u)$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\text{supp}(v)$ both cover $\,$ $\text{supp}(u)\wedge \text{supp}(v)$. $\,$ I'd like to show that $\text{supp}(u)\vee \text{supp}(v)$ $\,$ cover both $\,$ $\text{supp}(u)$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\text{supp}(v)$. Since I don't know that the join is, how could I possibly show this?

Comment: Another option would be to show that $L$ is graded (every maximal chain has the same length). Intuitively, I completely believe that because supports are nothing more that subsets of $[n]$, but I'm missing the details here...

Comment: This can be rephrased as a consequence of standard facts about matroids (though I would have to think a moment about how to do so).  Have you studied matroids?

Comment: @HughThomas I haven't. The professor of the course keeps bringing them up when only two people in class have studied them It's quite annoying :-/

Comment: The lattice in question is the lattice of flats of a matroid, and such lattices are known to be semi-modular.  Sorry not to be able to say more right now.  Matroids are really interesting and worth studying!  Perhaps if you asked your professor for a suggestion of something to read to learn about matroids, it would make the point that (a) you are willing to learn but (b) it's hard to do that without some help?